ShellRoute with ModalBototmSheetRoute in flutter
I’m implementing navigation within a BottomSheet using ModalBottomSheetRoute and go_router. However, I am unable to navigate to different paths within the BottomSheet. I have searched through various StackOverflow posts and issues, but I haven't found any cases similar to mine.
I want to set a shellRoute with a common ModalBottomSheetRoute and have the nested goRoutes navigate within that ModalBottomSheetRoute. However, in this situation, it does not show any errors.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> settingsNavigatorKey =
GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'settings');

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const MyHomePage(),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: settingsNavigatorKey,
      pageBuilder: (context, state, widget) {
        return BottomSheetPage(
          key: state.pageKey,
          showDragHandle: true,
          child: widget,
        );
      },
      // builder: (context, state, widget) {
      //   return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Center(child: widget));
      // },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: settingsNavigatorKey,
          path: '/test1',
          builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('This is test1 Page'),),
            body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      GoRouter.of(context).push('/test1/test2');
                    },
                    child: Text('go to test2')),
                Text('test1'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: settingsNavigatorKey,
              path: 'test2',
              builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: Center(child: Text('test2')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class BottomSheetPage<T> extends Page<T> {
  final Widget child;
  final bool showDragHandle;
  final bool useSafeArea;

  const BottomSheetPage({
    required this.child,
    this.showDragHandle = false,
    this.useSafeArea = true,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) => ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
        settings: this,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        showDragHandle: showDragHandle,
        useSafeArea: useSafeArea,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) => child,
      );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Nested Navigation BottomSheet'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
        child: Text("Push  the test1"),
        onPressed: () {
          GoRouter.of(context).push('/test1');
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}

problem video
Navigation works within the BottomSheet
